# How can I create an IF-THEN statement in Excel with two variables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function

```
      A           B           C(Output)
   ----------- ----------- ------
 |  65      |    0       |   2   |
   ----------- ----------- ------
 |  31      |    99      |   3   |
   ----------- ----------- ------
 |  0       |    36      |   2   |
   ----------- ------------ -----
 |  9       |    4       |   1   |
   ----------- ------------ -----
```

I am trying to create a formula, such as an `IF-THEN` statement, in Excel to look at both column A and/or column B and to calculate which of the two columns is higher and to categorize the values into either being a 0,1,2,3.

I have the formula down for looking at one column but I can not seem to incorporate 2 columns.

> =IF(A1=0,"0",IF(AND(A1>0,A1<=10),"1",IF(AND(A1>=11,A1<=80),"2",IF(AND(A1>=80),"3"))))

Criteria:
`0=0, 1-10=1, 11-80=2, >80=3`

Answer (score 2):

You can determine greater value using `MAX(A1,B1)` function :

```
IF(MAX(A1,B1)=0,0,IF(AND(MAX(A1,B1)>0,MAX(A1,B1)<=10),1,IF(AND(MAX(A1,B1)>10,MAX(A1,B1)<=80),2,IF(MAX(A1,B1)>80,3))))
```

If all values are positive number, you don't have to check lower bounds so you can simplify the function this way:

```
IF(MAX(A1,B1)=0,0,IF(MAX(A1,B1)<=10,1,IF(MAX(A1,B1)<=80,2,3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would make a third column C that is

```
=IF(A1 > B1, A1, B1)
```

Then you can just do you calculation on a single column.  You can hide it if needed.

Lets simplify the equation anyway, as for example if the value is over 80, we don't need to test further:

```
=if(C1 >= 80, "3", if(C1 >= 11,"2",if(C1=0,"0","1"))))
```

Note that once a test matches, the rest of the `if` is discarded.  So if it is over 80, it chooses 3 and ends.  If it is over 11, then it *must* be under 80 or it wouldn't have reached the second test.

So combining the two, replace C1 with the `if` that tests maximum:

```
=if(IF(A1 > B1, A1, B1) >= 80, "3", if(IF(A1 > B1, A1, B1) >= 11,"2",if(IF(A1 > B1, A1, B1)=0,"0","1"))))
```